# How to save a checkbox in dynamic ListView when exiting the app

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, checkbox, exit

I am new in Android and I was wondering if there is some way to save the following:
I have a custom adapter which contains a title and a checkbox.

The list is obtained from a database which is always changing so the listView is dynamic.
I cannot use SharedPreference because it only saves the position (and the list is moving) and I would like to find a way to save if the checkbox in each item is enabled or disabled when the user exits the application.

Basically it consist on an app which everybody can accessing a database to insert new values and its values are shown in a ListView in other interface, but the each element of the ListView has an Item with a checkbox and I would like to save the state of this checkbox for each user when user exiting the application.

The fast but heavy solution would be creating a particular database in each device to store all the item that the user read, but I asked to see any other solution.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBfls.png
For example, it can be people who did or did not press in the item "sport". So I want to save the state for this people who did it in their devices. 
Is cookies a solution?

Comment: We will not do all the work for you, what have you tried?

Comment: I have been looking for solutions here but I didn't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely understand the scenario. But you can save them to database in your onPause() method.